# How do you get the value of the selected option from a dynamically created select element?

Tags: javascript

I have a button to dynamically create select elements, which i created like this:

```
var units = units_array[0];
//ingredient unit of measurement drop down
var cell3= row.insertCell(2);
var unit_of_measure = document.createElement("select");
unit_of_measure.name = "unit_of_measure_select";
cell3.appendChild(unit_of_measure);

//Create and append the options
for (var i = 0; i < units.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = units[i];
    option.text = units[i];
    unit_of_measure.appendChild(option);
}
```

However, when I select it inside (inside a loop from another function) i get this error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined

Here is the code i am using to get to the select element which sits inside a table.

```
var table = document.getElementById('selected_ingredients');
var rowCount = table.rows.length; //empty table has 2 rows (header + something else?)
var cellsCount = table.rows[0].cells.length -1 ; //table width in cells by counting headers minus the last cell (delete)

for (var r = 1; r < rowCount; r++) { //loop through all rows (r) in table
    var $ingredient_dict = {}; //initiate dictionary for this ingredient

    for (var c = 0; c < cellsCount; c++) { //loop through each cell (c) in row
        var $cell = table.rows[r].cells[c];

        if ($cell.innerHTML.includes("select")) { //if its is 3rd iteration (3rd cell along = select box)
            alert("test");
            //not working - undefined value from generated select element
            var UOM = $cell.options[$cell.selectedIndex].value;
            alert(UOM);
```

I would like to return the value of the selected option in var UOM. I'm relatively new to js so apologies if this is simple.

Comment: The `select` element is a child of the cell, so you can't say `$cell.selectedIndex` or `$cell.options` because it's just the cell. Both of those evaluate to `undefined`. You want the child element in the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your if statement you can grab a handle to the select element:

```
$select = $cell.querySelector('select');
//then to grab the option and value
var UOM = $select.selectedOptions[0].value;
alert(UOM);
```

I would also recommend that in your if statement instead of checking for text in the innerHTML you:

```
$cell.querySelector('select');
```

This will return null which is the equivalent of false if no select element is present, but return true when an element is present.  The advantage is that if one of the cells contains the word 'select' for whatever reason if you are checking for the string 'select' it will return true and try to select the element that does not exist, however if you are looking for an element you just found it.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Also thank you for the .querySelector statement - i will implement that as well!